# Undoing desktop integration in VMware Fusion and Windows 7 Guest

Tags: windows-7, vmware-fusion

I originally configured my Windows 7 VM to share "My Documents" and "Desktop" between my Mac (Yosemite) and the Windows 7 VM. After undoing this integration in the VM settings, however, I constantly receive a warning message stating that

> Windows cannot access \\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Desktop

I have changed the location of Documents to be back on C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Docuemnts and this fixed the same error regarding \\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents but I'm not sure how to change this setting for the Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This fix on the VMware Communities site worked for me:

> To fix the issue, while logged into the Windows 7 VM on the new MacBook, I went into the VM properties and removed all the Shared Folders that were set up for it - including the Mirroring settings for Desktop, Documents, Music and Pictures.  This cuased my Windows 7 VM to automatically log me out of the session and re-login again. Once I relogged in, the errors were gone - but then of course were were also my mirrored settings.
>
> So, I then had to recreate the mirrored/shared folders by just going back into the VM properties (while still logged into the same new Windows 7 session immediately following the previous removal effort) and selecting "Share Folders on your Mac" and selecting the mirrored folders I wanted again (e.g. Desktop, Documents, etc.).  This once again automatically prompted me to log out of the current Windows 7 session in the VM... once I re-logged back in the shared folders and mirroring settings were working again as I wanted - still without the errors.

[Source](https://communities.vmware.com/message/1638676)